# How do I send parameters to the method in a ContractForm

Tags: reactjs, truffle

I have a React component

```
<ContractForm contract="SomeContract" method="setEmployee" />
```

My solidity `setEmployee` method looks like this

```
function setEmployee(
   address employeeAddress,
   uint _statusType
) public onlyOwner {
  ...
}
```

How do I send an address and a string to this `setEmployee` method from my React front end? Where exactly do I pass parameters to the method in the contract?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the actual function to ContractForm, you're currently just passing a string.

```
<ContractForm contract="SomeContract" method={setEmployee} />
```

Then within the ContractForm component you can call the function via the method prop:

```
this.props.method(employeeAddress, _statusType);
```

**Edit**
Was my understanding that setEmployee was in a parent component. I'm not familiar with the use of Truffle/.sol files in React.

Comment: The function is in a different .sol file. As far as I understand, the React component merely looks for a function name